# What is the best reliable weight/power ration achieved by a pre-1911 plane?

Tags: aviation-history

From the article "DAYTON BOYS EMULATE GREAT SANTOS-DUMONT" that appeared on December 18, 1903, it can be calculated that the apparatus, which took off one day before, flew **700 lb / 16 hp = 19.84 kg / hp**.
Are there planes, built by others, before say 1911, that came close to this performance?

[1903-12-18, “Dayton Boys Emulate Great Santos-Dumont”, The Dayton Daily News, Ohio, US, December 18, 1903, p. 8.](https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.05001/?sp=12)

> **DAYTON BOYS EMULATE GREAT SANTOS-DUMONT**
>
> TESTS HELD IN SECRET ON THE CAROLINA COAST.
>
> Kitty Hawk, N. C., Dec. 17. We have made four successful flights this
> morning, all against a 21-mile wind. We started from the level, with
> engine power alone. Our average speed through the air was 31 miles.
> Our longest time in the air was 57 seconds.  ORVILLE WRIGHT.
>
> The above telegram was received by Bishop Milton Wright of this city last
> evening from his sons Wilbur and Orville Wright, who have been for
> several months at Kitty Hawk on the coast of North Carolina
> experimenting with a flying machine, announcing the complete success
> of their invention which they call the “Wright Flyer.”  Thursday
> morning they made four successful flights against a wind of 21 miles
> an hour, starting from a level and going at the rate of ten miles per
> hour, which would be equal to a rate of 31 miles per hour in a calm.
> No power was used in starting the flight except two aerial propellers
> driven by a powerful but light gasoline engine. The landings were all
> made easily and without injury to either the machine or operator. The
> Wright brothers have been carrying on experiments for the past six or
> seven years, and have built three previous machines for gliding by
> means of which they attained proficiency in the control of their
> apparatus. This year is the first time they have attempted to drive
> their machine by power.
>
> **THE WRIGHT FLYER.** The “Wright Flyer” is a true flying machine. It has no gas bag or balloon attachments of any kind, but is supported by
> a pair of aero-curves or wings, having an area or 510 square feet. It
> measures a little more than 40 feet from tip to tip and the extreme
> fore and aft dimension is about 20 feet. The weight, including the
> body of the aviator, is **slightly over 700 pounds**. The machine is
> driven by a pair of aerial screw propellers placed just behind the
> main wings. The power is supplied by a gasoline motor designed and
> built by the Messrs. Wright in their own shop. It is of the four-cycle
> type and has four cylinders. The pistons are four inches in diameter,
> and have a four-inch stroke. At the speed of 1200 revolutions a minute
> the engine develops **16 brake horse power**, with a consumption of
> little less than 10 pounds of gasoline per hour. The weight, including
> carburetter and fly-wheel, is 152 pounds. The wings, though apparently
> very light, have been tested to more than six times the regular load,
> and it is claimed for the entire structure that it is a practical
> machine, capable of withstanding the shock of repeated landings, not a
> mere toy which must be entirely rebuilt after each flight.
>
> The dispatch from Norfolk, Va., published in the morning dailies
> contains much that is inaccurate and was based on imperfect or
> unauthentic information. The credit for the success of the “Wright
> Flyer” is jointly due to both Wilbur and Orville as the invention has
> been the result of their joint labours.